# Offline JavaScript speech recognition library

Tags: library, javascript, offline, speech-recognition

[Annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) is a great solution for speech recognition, but it needs internet connection.

I was wondering if there is a simple solution for offline speech recognition in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, check [Pocketsphinx.js](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js) a pocketsphinx port created with emscripten

To learn more about pocketsphinx check the [tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial).